Cant ignore the absence of whitespaces between keywords with bnfc
I'm writing a grammar for BASIC using BNFC.
The grammar is mostly working, except that it wont accept the keywords without spaces between them, and i cannot figure out how to configure the grammar file or patch the generated files to do so.
for instance, both
10 A = 1 : PRINT A : PRINT A + 1

and
10 A=1:PRINTA:PRINTA+1

are valid in old basic interpreters.
